# how to add multiple space between columns in Unix

Tags: text-processing, columns

I have a file looks like this

```
0 1 2 3 4 1 0 0
1 2 3 5 0 1 0 0
```

I want to add more (multiple) space between the columns and get something like this

```
0      1      2      3      4
1      2      3      5      0
```

I tried something with column -t, but still it does not give the space that I want.

Comment: Try `col -x`? It uses spaces rather than tabs.

Comment: what happened to the last few columns? `1 0 0` from line 1 and `1 0 0` from line 2?

Comment: @DopeGhoti, may as well throw that in an answer.

Comment: Have you tried the `-o` flag? eg `column -o '           '  -t file.txt`

Comment: Do any of the provided answers solve your problem? If so, don't forget to mark one with the checkmark; thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With coreutils, you could convert spaces to tabs with `tr`, and then convert tabs back to multiple spaces with `expand`:

```
$ tr ' ' '\t' < file | expand
0       1       2       3       4       1       0       0
1       2       3       5       0       1       0       0
```

The default tab stops are 8 spaces, but you can adjust that e.g.

```
$ tr ' ' '\t' < file | expand -t 10
0         1         2         3         4         1         0         0
1         2         3         5         0         1         0         0
```

Answer (score 1):

Some more ideas that will work with your sample data:

```
$ a="0 1 2 3 4 1 0 0"

$ echo "$a"
0 1 2 3 4 1 0 0

$ echo "${a// /                 }"
0                 1                 2                 3                 4                 1                 0                 0

$ echo "$a" |sed 's/ /             /g'
0             1             2             3             4             1             0             0

$ echo "${a// /$'\t'}"
0   1   2   3   4   1   0   0

$ echo "$a" |sed 's/ /\t\t/g'
0       1       2       3       4       1       0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

to format the columns evenly, you could use awk:

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i <= NF; i++) { printf "%-7s", $i } print "" }' < input > output
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E 's/\S+\s/&     /g' your_monospace.file

awk -v OFS="     " '{$1=$1}1' your_monospaced.file

perl -pale '$_ = join $" x 5, @F' your_monospaced.file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `col -x`? It uses spaces rather than tabs.